# either or with more than two alternatives

Tags: phrase-request

How to say a phrase like this:

> Either "specifically" or "explicitly" or any other adverb is just wrong in that sentence.

"Either" is usually used with two alternatives. What is used when we have more than two alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the Oxford Dictionary, you can use **either** with more than two alternatives

**[either](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/either)**

> Used before the first of two (**or occasionally more**) given alternatives (the other being introduced by ‘or’)

Answer (score 0):

You usually use either when there are two alternatives, but it is also correct to use it when you refer to more than two choices. For example:

You can contact us either by phone or by email (two choices).

You can contact us either by phone, by email, or by letter (three choices).